# Including Django template from one app in another app template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to include a template that show user posts on the user's profile. I have used an inclusion tag however it the posts are not displaying on the user's profile. It does, however, work on the home page, which is set to be the PostListView from that app.

Inclusion tag in `userprofile_detail.html`:

```
<div class="content-right">
    {% include 'feed/userpost_list_inner.html' %}
</div>
```

The actual list of post (the feed) in `userpost_list.html`:

```
{% for post in userpost_list %}
    <div class="post">
        <h2 class="post-title">{{ userpost.post.title }}</h2>
        <p class="accent">{{ post.author }}</p>
        <p class="accent">{{ post.post_date }}</p>
        <p class="body">{{ post.post_body }}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm not getting any errors, however the posts are not displaying on the user's profile page.

**Edit:** Here is my feed app views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404,redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from feed.models import UserPost,UserComment
from feed.forms import PostForm,CommentForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin

from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                    DetailView,CreateView,
                                    UpdateView,DeleteView)

User = get_user_model()

# Create your views here.

##Posts Views
class HomeView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = 'login'
    model = UserPost
    ordering = ['-post_date']

class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = 'login'
    redirect_field_name = '/userpost_list.html'
    model = UserPost

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super(CreatePostView, self).form_valid(form)

class UpdatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = 'login'
    redirect_field_name = '/userpost_detail.html'
    form_class = PostForm
    model = UserPost

class DeletePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
    model = UserPost
    select_related = ('user',)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('userpost_list')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)

    def delete(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return super().delete(*args,**kwargs)



##Comments Views
def add_comment_to_post(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(UserPost,pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('userpost_list',pk=userpost.pk)
        else:
            form = CommentForm()
        return render(request,'feed/userpost_list.html',{'form':form})
```

Here is my users app views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from users.forms import UserForm,UserProfileForm
from users.models import UserProfileInfo

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                    DetailView,CreateView,
                                    UpdateView,DeleteView)

# Create your views here.
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Account now active")

        else:
            print("Login Unsuccessful")
            return HttpResponse("Username and/or password are not correct")

    else:
        return render(request,'login.html',{})

def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

            profile.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    return render(request,'register.html',{
                                        'user_form':user_form,
                                        'profile_form':profile_form,
                                        'registered':registered
                                        })

@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

class UserListView(ListView):
    model = UserProfileInfo
    ordering = ['-join_date']

class UserProfileView(DetailView):
    model = UserProfileInfo

class UserEditProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = '/users_detail.html'
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    model = UserProfileInfo
```

feed app models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

# Create your models here.
class UserPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='userpost',null=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=False)
    post_body = models.TextField(max_length=1000,blank=False)

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class UserComment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('feed.UserPost',related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='usercomment')
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment_body = models.TextField(max_length=500)

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("userpost_list")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

users app models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from users.choices import *

# Create your models here.
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    join_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    user_type = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES,default=1)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=500,default='about')
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    dribbble = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    github = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

users app urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from users import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.UserListView.as_view(),name='user_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.UserProfileView.as_view(),name='user_profile'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit$',views.UserEditProfileView.as_view(),name='user-profile-edit'),
    url(r'^login/$',views.user_login,name='user_login'),
    url(r'^logout/$',views.user_logout,name='user_logout',kwargs={'next_page':'/'}),
    url(r'^register/$',views.register,name='register'),
]
```

feed app urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from feed import views

app_name = 'feed'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^new/$',views.CreatePostView.as_view(),name='new_post'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$',views.UpdatePostView.as_view(),name='edit_post'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$',views.DeletePostView.as_view(),name='delete_post'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/comment/$',views.add_comment_to_post,name='add_comment_to_post'),
]
```

Error traceback from Answer 1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/garrettlove/Desktop/evverest/users/views.py", line 83, in userprofile
    user = get_object_or_404(UserProfileInfo, user__id=pk)
NameError: name 'get_object_or_404' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `userpost` object is not available in `userprofile_detail.html`. It is only available in `userpost_list.html`.

Make it available by sending it to `userprofile_detail.html` also using the views and it will show up.

```
from feed.models import UserPost
from .models import UserProfileInfo
from django.shortcuts import render,get_list_or_404,get_object_or_404

def userprofile(request,pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(UserProfileInfo, user__id=pk)
    userpost_list = UserPost.objects.filter(author__id=pk)

    context={'user':user, 'userpost_list':userpost_list}
    return render(request, 'yourtemplate/html', context)
```

Now in **urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.userprofile,name='user_profile'),
```

Comment: Wait how do I do that? I understand what you're saying I just don't know how to do it lol

Comment: Add your `views.py` in question.

Comment: Just added them

Comment: What's under `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):`?

Comment: So like this:`class UserProfileView(DetailView):
 model = UserProfileInfo
 template_name = 'userprofileinfo_detail.html'
 
 userpost_list = UserPost.objects.filter(user__id=user.id)
 context={'userpost_list':userpost_list}` I don't know how to format comment code better sorry

Comment: yes you need to fetch the result, and send it using `context` dictionary.

Comment: it gives error `NameError: name 'user' is not defined`

Comment: There will be a `field` user in post which relates post to user using foreign key. Use that. Or include `models.py` and `urls.py` in question. I will look into it.

Comment: I just added them. Sorry I'm a beginner so I understand what you're saying (for the most part) I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: It's ok, every one is a beginner once, I too struggled a lot when I started 1 year back. I have updated the answer have a look now.

Comment: Thank I appreciate it. It now gives this error though: `NameError: name 'pk' is not defined`

Comment: Does this no longer work with userprofileinfo_detail.html as my template? It's giving me an error with that template

Comment: It should work but you try changing the name of html file.

Comment: I don't think I changed it, what should it be

Comment: you just give a name to html file inside, like `userprofile.html` and put it inside `appname/template/appname/userprofile.html` and then `return render(request, 'appname/usrprofile.html', context)`

Comment: It's giving me errors with the user info I had on the page before, but it did work.